# How do I parse multiple xml attributes to php variables?

Tags: php, xml

I have the following PHP code that I am using to extract xml attributeds to a php variables.

```
$dataPOST= '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:c2b="http://cps.huawei.com/cpsinterface/c2bpayment">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <c2b:C2BPaymentConfirmationRequest>
         <TransactionType>PayBill</TransactionType>
         <TransID>1234560000007031</TransID>
         <TransTime>20140227082020</TransTime>
         <TransAmount>123.00</TransAmount>
         <BusinessShortCode>12345</BusinessShortCode>
         <BillRefNumber>TX1001</BillRefNumber>
         <InvoiceNumber></InvoiceNumber>
         <OrgAccountBalance>12345.00</OrgAccountBalance>
         <ThirdPartyTransID></ThirdPartyTransID>
         <MSISDN>254722703614</MSISDN>
         <KYCInfo>
            <KYCName>[Personal Details][First Name]</KYCName>
            <KYCValue>Hoiyor</KYCValue>
        </KYCInfo>
        <KYCInfo>
            <KYCName>[Personal Details][Middle Name]</KYCName>
            <KYCValue>G</KYCValue>
        </KYCInfo>
        <KYCInfo>
            <KYCName>[Personal Details][Last Name]</KYCName>
            <KYCValue>Chen</KYCValue>
        </KYCInfo>
      </c2b:C2BPaymentConfirmationRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';

$xml = @simplexml_load_string($dataPOST);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("soap","http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
$xml->registerXPathNamespace ("c2b", "http://cps.huawei.com/cpsinterface/c2bpayment");

$xml2 = $xml->xpath("//soap:Envelope/soap:Body/c2b:C2BPaymentConfirmationRequest");

$TransactionType = (string) $xml2[0]->TransactionType;
$TransID = (string) $xml2[0]->TransID;
$TransTime = (string) $xml2[0]->TransTime;
$TransAmount = (string) $xml2[0]->TransAmount;
$BusinessShortCode = (string) $xml2[0]->BusinessShortCode;
$BillRefNumber = (string) $xml2[0]->BillRefNumber;
$InvoiceNumber = (string) $xml2[0]->InvoiceNumber;
$OrgAccountBalance = (string) $xml2[0]->OrgAccountBalance;
$ThirdPartyTransID = (string) $xml2[0]->ThirdPartyTransID;
$MSISDN = (string) $xml2[0]->MSISDN;

echo 'TransactionType: '.$TransactionType.'<br/>';
echo 'TransID: '.$TransID.'<br/>';
echo 'TransTime: '.$TransTime.'<br/>';
echo 'TransAmount: '.$TransAmount.'<br/>';
echo 'BusinessShortCode: '.$BusinessShortCode.'<br/>';
echo 'BillRefNumber: '.$BillRefNumber.'<br/>';
echo 'InvoiceNumber: '.$InvoiceNumber.'<br/>';
echo 'OrgAccountBalance: '.$OrgAccountBalance.'<br/>';
echo 'ThirdPartyTransID: '.$ThirdPartyTransID.'<br/>';
echo 'MSISDN: '.$MSISDN.'<br/>';
```

This code is working fine and I am able to extract most of the attributes from the xml but I am now struggling with the last few attributes. How should I handle the following part of the xml and parse it to PHP variable?

```
<KYCInfo>
        <KYCName>[Personal Details][First Name]</KYCName>
        <KYCValue>Hoiyor</KYCValue>
    </KYCInfo>
    <KYCInfo>
        <KYCName>[Personal Details][Middle Name]</KYCName>
        <KYCValue>G</KYCValue>
    </KYCInfo>
    <KYCInfo>
        <KYCName>[Personal Details][Last Name]</KYCName>
        <KYCValue>Chen</KYCValue>
    </KYCInfo>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query the DOM held in your `$xml2` variable:

```
$query = './KYCInfo';
$elements = $xml2[0]->xpath($query);
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    print $element->KYCName . PHP_EOL;
    print $element->KYCValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```

This should result in

```
[Personal Details][First Name]
Hoiyor
[Personal Details][Middle Name]
G
[Personal Details][Last Name]
Chen
```

which you can assign to variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath predicate to get `KYCInfo` where child element `KYCName` value equals certain string, for example, '[Personal Details][Last Name]' :

```
$query = "KYCInfo[KYCName='[Personal Details][Last Name]']/KYCValue";
$MiddleName = (string)$xml2[0]->xpath($query)[0];
```

**<kbd>[`eval.in demo`](https://eval.in/583247)</kbd>**

Use the same approach to get first name and middle name...

Comment: BTW, everything that your current code query from the XML, including `KYCValue` in the above snippet, are XML *elements* not attribute. Using the correct standard terms will help you come up with a better keyword when doing research on the internet.